# Find who delete message in discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to get who delete a message. Something like this: `message.deleted_by` would be the solution.

This is my code:

````
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    channel = client.get_channel(737364723107889304)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=' ᴠᴇᴛᴇʀᴀɴᴏꜱ ɢᴜᴀʀᴅɪᴀɴ', description=f"{message.delete_by} deletou uma mensagem", color=discord.Color.dark_red())
    embed.add_field(name="Informamos que:",value=f"{message.author} **teve uma mensagem com o seguinte conteudo deletada:** ```{message.content}```")
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
````

Does any one know how can I do it? (after some search i've found the solution)

This solve my problem:

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    async for message in message.guild.audit_logs(action=discord.AuditLogAction.message_delete, limit=1):
        delete_by = "{0.user}".format(message)
```

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In particular, "How do I implement this feature" is discussed as being off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that's pretty simple:

````
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
channel = client.get_channel(737364723107889304)
embed = discord.Embed(title=' ᴠᴇᴛᴇʀᴀɴᴏꜱ ɢᴜᴀʀᴅɪᴀɴ', description=f"{message.author} deletou uma mensagem", color=discord.Color.dark_red())
embed.add_field(name="Informamos que:",value=f"{message.author} **teve uma mensagem com o seguinte conteudo deletada:** ```{message.content}```")
await channel.send(embed=embed)
````

All you need to do is to change message.delete_by to message.author

Comment: AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'member'

Comment: @MarcoAntonioAmorelli `message.author` not `message.member`

Comment: but "message.author" returns the author of message delete. But I want to get WHO delete the message.

Comment: @client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    async for message in message.guild.audit_logs(action=discord.AuditLogAction.message_delete, limit=1):
        delete_by = "{0.user}".format(message)


this works for me ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^